# android check internet connection with timer

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, internet-connection

I try to check internet connection with timer.i want to check connection for example every 5 seconds.i wrote some codes but i have error this is a my source

```
public class BroadCastSampleActivity extends Activity {

TimerTask mTimerTask;
Timer mTimer;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mTimerTask = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                    && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                    && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "net Started",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }
    };

    mTimer = new Timer();
    mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(mTimerTask, 1000, 5000);

}
```

}

and this is a my log error
[image]
what am i doing wrong? if anyone knows solution please help me
P.s
i want to check internet connection for example like Facebook  and i don't know my solution (i mean  timer) is better way.

Comment: You Have no need of Time....if You Add time to compare it manualey then app will slow working because of time so without time do it....

Comment: No one Developer want to make app slo working and you are one who are doing to make app slow working....With manualey add time Limit....

Answer (score 0):

You can not call toast from non UI thread. So, handler will help you. If you will remove Toast in production code error will go by itself. More over here is the workaround with handler.

```
Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    mTimerTask = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                        && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                        && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {

                handler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "net Started",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });


                }

            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "net Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

with

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "net Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```